# Entity Framework Core Is Not Saving Changing to the Database After Setting the Entity State into Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

In my case, I have a singleton service that depends on a scoped service, which is a DbContext implementation.

The singleton service basically is a data access layer that performs the CRUD operation into the SQL server database.

In the data access layer, I have injected the IServiceScopeFactory to get an instance of my DbContext per request.

The following code block is showing a sample of the data access implementation:

```
public class Repository<IEntity> : IRepository<IEntity> where IEntity : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public Repository(
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void Add(IEntity entity)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCPSContext>();
            _context.Set<IEntity>().Add(entity);
            scope.Dispose();
        }

    }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Task<int> result;
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCPSContext>();
            result = _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            scope.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Registration of the data access service:

```
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

Registration of the dbContext:

```
var connection = configuration.GetConnectionString("PCPS_CS");
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = connection;
        services.AddDbContext<PCPSContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("PCPS.API")));
```

The problem is, the changes are not reflected in the SQL server database after saving the changes using EFcore, also there is no exception occurred during the process of adding an entity.

I'm interested to know what causes the data to be not reflected in the database.

Comment: Have you tried calling `_context.SaveChangesAsync();` immediately after `_context.Set<IEntity>().Add(entity);`? Just so check if that works and might be related to that `Dispose()`

Comment: It's working in this way, but I don't understand what's different between call it immediately or call later on. @devcrp

Comment: As others suggest, try adding the `await` operator to the `SaveChangesAsync`. If you're awaiting in the upper layer, the Dispose() has been already been called. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: I tried it, and I've got the same result. @devcrp

Comment: Then the last shot is to remove the `using` and the `Dispose()` altogether, perhaps disposing it after the Add and create a new instance later in the SaveChanges is not a good idea. Not sure what's the best approach here given that the Repository is a singleton.

Comment: @devcrp
Yes I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes are not saved since your are calling the `async` function without `await`.

Change:

```
result = _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

to

```
result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Also there is no need to call for `Dispose` inside the `using` block. The object is disposed automatically after the using block ends.

Comment: I do use await operator when I call the save changes function in the manager layer. 
A good point to mention about the Dispose function, thanks.

Comment: You need to use it as well here, or call the sync version (_context.SaveChanges()).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't used `await` keyword.The `await` operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing async method until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand completes

```
public async int SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        int result;
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCPSContext>();
            result =await  _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            scope.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the await keyword when I call the function from the manager. Thank you for your effort.